# Mixing Spring tx with task

Tags: java, spring, transactions, scheduled-tasks

In Spring 3.0, are scheduled task methods annotated with `@Scheduled` already transactional? If not, will annotating the same method as `@Transactional` work? That is, will the scheduler honour the transaction annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I known, the answer is no, `@Scheduled` doesn't care about transactions. Add `@Transactional` manually, it should work (also you may check it yourself by enabling debug messages and watching to log).